# Decompose floating-point number

Tags: c#, c, floating-point

Given a floating-point number, I would like to separate it into a sum of parts, each with a given number of bits. For example, given 3.1415926535 and told to separate it into base-10 parts of 4 digits each, it would return 3.141 + 5.926E-4 + 5.350E-8. Actually, I want to separate a double (which has 52 bits of precision) into three parts with 18 bits of precision each, but it was easier to explain with a base-10 example. I am not necessarily averse to tricks that use the internal representation of a standard double-precision IEEE float, but I would really prefer a solution that stays purely in the floating point realm so as to avoid any issues with endian-dependency or non-standard floating point representations.

No, this is not a homework problem, and, yes, this has a practical use. If you want to ensure that floating point multiplications are exact, you need to make sure that any two numbers you multiply will never have more than half the digits that you have space for in your floating point type. Starting from this kind of decomposition, then multiplying all the parts and convolving, is one way to do that. Yes, I could also use an arbitrary-precision floating-point library, but this approach is likely to be faster when only a few parts are involved, and it will definitely be lighter-weight.

Comment: Why you used `C` and `C#` tags? Specially both?

Comment: I am happy to work in either. As far as I can tell, both have the same capabilities and will support the same approaches to this question.

Comment: Isn't there a conflict between "avoid any issues with endian-dependency or non-standard floating point representations" and "separate a double (which has 52 bits of precision) into three parts with 18 bits of precision each"?

Comment: The assumption is wrong. Squaring double(1<<27 + 1) is inexact, despite it having "more digits than you have space for in your floating point type.".

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy: No. Why would there be? It's easier to see with integers. `i & UCHAR_MAX` is the low byte, regardless of endianness.

Comment: You mention a lot of things in your question that make it unclear.. "Actually, I want to separate a double", "insure fp multiplcations are exact"... what are you trying to achieve? What is wrong with `Decimal`?

Comment: If you want to accomodate non-standard floating point representations, what about a format with 53 bits of precision? Or 51? Or, to be perverse, either 51 or 67 bits, depending on a flag bit?

Comment: @ThomasPardon-McCarthy: Pi in binary, separated into 8-bit parts, is 11.00100100001111110110101010001... = 11.001001 + 0.00000000001111 + 0.0000000000000011011010 + ... This is a real mathematical fact, not dependent on endian-ness. The fact that some computers internally write these digits in the opposite direction doesn't affect this result.

Comment: @MSalters: Squaring (double) (1 << 27 + 1) is inexact precisely because that number has more digits (2 * 28 bits) than a double has room for (52 bits). If you had started with a number of 21 bits or less, the square would be exact.

Comment: @user624095: I know, the choice was intentional. My point was that your wording is ambiguous at best. After all, my example has only 4 bits set. You probably intended something like "the number of trailing zeroes must be at least 52".

Comment: @MSalters: Edited to "any two numbers you multiply will never have more than half the digits that you have space for". Thanks.

Comment: @user624095: That's a special case (26/26 split), which is sufficient but not necessary. I.e. you don't need to make sure.

Comment: Ok, I see your point. I was confused by your claim that a double has 52 bits. As far as I know, the C standard only requires DBL_DIG to be at least 10, which is around 33 bits, so if you really want to accomodate non-standard floating-point formats, your code would have to work with, for example, 37-bit or 79-bit precisions. In that case, I don't think hard-codng "into three parts with 18 bits of precision each" is such a good idea. If you actually assume a certain format (IEEE 754?), with exactly 52 bits, why not use the layout of that specific format?

Comment: For this purpose, you cannot treat a 64-bit binary IEEE 754 number as having at most 52 significant bits and still preserve all the data in two doubles. For normal doubles, there is a leading bit that is known to be non-zero due to normalization, and so does not need to be stored physically. That bit matters during multiplication.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: A 53-bit significand can be split into two doubles each with 26 or fewer significant bits in its significand. The sign of the low double acts as a significand bit. When the high 26 bits are prepared, they are rounded. Then the (signed) remainder is either exactly 1/2 at the point of rounding or is less than 1/2, so its most significant bit is at most one more position further down from the rounding point.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> If you want to ensure that floating point multiplications are exact, you need to make sure that any two numbers you multiply will never have more than half the digits that you have space for in your floating point type.

Exactly. This technique can be found in Veltkamp/Dekker multiplication. While accessing the bits of the representation as in other answers is a possibility, you can also do with only floating-point operations. There is one instance in [this blog post](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/05/01/A-conversionless-conversion-function2). The part you are interested in is:

```
Input: f; coef is 1 + 2^N
 p = f * coef;
 q = f - p;
 h = p + q;  // h contains the 53-N highest bits of f
 l = f - h;  // l contains the N lowest bits of f
```

`*`, `-`, and `+` must be exactly the IEEE 754 operations at the precision of `f` for this to work. On Intel architectures, these operations are provided by the SSE2 instruction set. Visual C sets the precision of the historical FPU to 53 bits in the prelude of the C programs it compiles, which also helps.

Comment: For completeness: The operations must be performed with round-to-nearest (usually the default rounding mode). If `f * coef` does not overflow, no other operation will overflow. This works if `f` is subnormal or normal. This works for decimal arithmetic too, or any radix. (All per Muller et al, *Handbook of Floating-Point Arithmetic*, 2010, page 133.)

Comment: Fantastic, this is exactly what I was looking for, and the references have pointed me to a treasure-trove of floating-point knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits` and `C#`'s bitwise operators.  You seem to be familiar with IEEE floating point formats so I'll not add more detail.

I just noticed tag `C`.  In this case, you can use a `union` and do pretty much the same.

The real problems you have are:

1. Handling the implicit leading "1".  In border cases, this would lead you to +0 / -0 situations.  I can predict your code will be full of special cases because of this reason.
2. With very low exponents, your will get them out of range even before you consider the "leading 1" problem.  Even if in-range you will need to resort to subnormals.  Given the big gap between normal and subnormal numbers, I also dare to predict that there will be several ranges of valid floating point numbers that will have no possible representation in this scheme.

Except as noted above, handling of the exponent should be trivial:  subtract 18 and 36 for the second and third 18-bit parts (and then find the leading 1, further decreasing it, of course).

Ugly solution?  IEEE 754 **is** ugly by itself in the border cases.  Big-endian/little-endian is the least of your problems.

Personally, I think this will get too complicated for your original objective.  Just stick to a simple solution to your problem:  find a function that counts trailing zeroes (does the standard itself defines one?  I could be confusing with a libtrary) and ensure that the sum is > 52.  Yes, your requirement of "half the digits(?)" (you meant 26 bits, right?) is stronger than necessary.  And also wrong because it doesn't take into account the implicit 1.  This is also why above I didn't say >= 52, but > 52.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this is a valid solution, but it's ugly. The bit-mask part for the mantissa is straightforward, but because the exponent is biased, you have to do a good bit of work to get the right exponents for each part. Finally, this is endian-dependent, isn't it? Is there any way to get a endian-ness flag in C# so I can have separate code-paths for each case?

Comment: I think I see. As long as I take the mantissa and exponent parts of the 64 bits and re-interpret them as integers rather than bit patterns, their endian-ness doesn't matter. I realized this when looking at MSalter's answer and thinking about how to write frexp in C#, so credit goes to both you and him for enlightening me. Thanks!

Comment: @user624095  Responded in my answer.  It was too long.

Answer (score 1):

The c way of decomposing numbers would be `abs` and `frexp`, which remove sign and exponent. The result necessarily lies in [ 0.5 , 1.0 ). Multiplying that by `1<<N` means the integer part (obtained by `modf`) contains the top N bits.

Answer (score 0):

Numerically, in general, you can shift left n digits, convert to integer and subtract.

```
  a = (3.1415926535)*1000 = 3141.5926535

  b = (int) a             = 3141

  c = a - (double) b      = 0.5926535   << can convert this to 0.5926, etc.

  d = (double) b / 1000   = 3.141 << except this MIGHT NOT be exact in base 2!!
```

But the principal is the same if you do all the mults/divides by powers of 2.

Comment: s/MIGHT NOT/WILL NOT/. You're multiplying by `0.001`, which does not have a finite binary representation.